# Nuxt build not working with connected other domains except root domain

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, nuxt.js

I need some help with nuxtjs build version which is working fine in my main domain for example my domain is

**test-domain.com** my build is working fine, but in my other connected domain like **test2-domain.com** _nuxt folder is not capturing it's giving me 404 in _nuxt folder, so this build is basically this build generated only for my **test-domain.com** not for other domains.

I am using Nginx server, here I am attaching my nuxt.config.js file I hope i will get some suggestion or help from all of you

```
export default {
    /*
    ** Nuxt target
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-target
    */
    target: 'server',
  
    /*
    ** Headers of the page
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
    */
    head: {
      meta: [
        { charset: 'utf-8' },
        { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
        { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.npm_package_description || '' }
      ],
      link: [
        { rel: 'stylesheet', type: 'text/css', href: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css' }
      ],
      script: [
        // { src: 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        // { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        // { src: 'https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        // { src: '/popover.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/popper.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        // { src: '/libs/@shopify/draggable/lib/es5/draggable.bundle.legacy.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/autosize/dist/autosize.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/chart.js/dist/Chart.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        // { src: '/libs/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/highlightjs/highlight.pack.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/jquery-mask-plugin/dist/jquery.mask.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/list.js/dist/list.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/quill/dist/quill.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/libs/chart.js/Chart.extension.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/colorPick.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/feather.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: '/custom.js' },
        { src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bodymovin/5.5.9/lottie.min.js', mode: 'client' },
        { src: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/notyf@3/notyf.min.js', mode: 'client' }
      ]
    },
    /*
    ** Global CSS
    */
    loading: {
      color: '#377dff',
      height: '1.5px'
    },
    css: [
      // '@/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
      '@/assets/css/theme.css',
      '@/assets/css/style.css',
      '@/assets/fonts/feather/feather.css',
      '@/assets/css/colorPick.min.css',
      '@/assets/libs/highlightjs/styles/vs2015.css',
      '@/assets/libs/quill/dist/quill.core.css',
      '@/assets/libs/quill/dist/quill.snow.css',
      '@/node_modules/@voerro/vue-tagsinput/dist/style.css',
      '@/assets/libs/notyf.css'
      // '@/assets/css/select2.min.css'
      // '@/assets/libs/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css'
    ],
    /*
    ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
    ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
    */
    plugins: [
      '~/plugins/general-intialization.js',
      '~/plugins/vue-filters.js',
      '~/plugins/vee-validate.js',
      '~/plugins/axios-interceptor.js',
      '~/plugins/service-interceptor.js',
      { src: '~/plugins/vue-plugin-in-nuxt.js', ssr: false },
      { src: '~/plugins/notyf', ssr: false }
    ],
  
    /*
    ** Auto import components
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-components
    */
    components: true,
  
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
    */
    buildModules: [
      // Doc: https://github.com/nuxt-community/eslint-module
      '@nuxtjs/eslint-module'
    ],
  
    /*
    ** Nuxt.js modules
    */
    modules: [
      // Doc: https://http.nuxtjs.org
      '@nuxt/http',
      '@nuxtjs/axios',
      '@nuxtjs/auth',
      ['cookie-universal-nuxt', { alias: 'cookiz' }]
    ],
    axios: {
      // baseURL: 'http://localhost:' + process.env.PORT // Used as fallback if no runtime config is provided
      baseURL: '/'
    },
    auth: {
      strategies: {
        local: {
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: '/api/user/signin', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
            user: { url: '/api/user/me', method: 'get', propertyName: 'data' },
            logout: false
          },
          redirect: {
            login: '/feedback',
            logout: '/auth/login'
          }
        }
      }
    },
  
    /*
    ** Server Middleware
    */
    serverMiddleware: [
      {
        path: '/api', handler: '~/server'
      }
    ],
  
    /*
    ** For deployment you might want to edit host and port
    */
    server: {
      port: process.env.PORT, // default: 3000
      host: 'localhost' // default: localhost
    },
  
    /*
    ** Build configuration
    ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
    */
    build: {
      transpile: [
        'vee-validate/dist/rules'
      ]
    },
    router: {
      extendRoutes (router, resolve) {
        router.push({ path: '/', component: resolve(__dirname, '@/pages/feedback/index.vue') })
        router.push({ path: '/setting', component: resolve(__dirname, '@/pages/company/index.vue') })
        router.push({ path: '/setting/company', component: resolve(__dirname, '@/pages/company/index.vue') })
        router.push({ path: '/company/create', component: resolve(__dirname, '@/pages/company/create.vue') })
        router.push({ path: '/verify/email', component: resolve(__dirname, '@/pages/verify-email.vue') })
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was server level issue, we shifted to another node server and everything works fine so if anyone have faced the same issue please try with a different server I hope it will work for you also